# ArcGIS Pro error 000732: "Input Layer: Dataset xyz does not exist or is not supported" when using arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, error-000732

Below is the code I wrote in ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro. The layer from "arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management" is created (name changes in each iteration as "Layer_%s" %(FIPS)). But "arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management" is not accepting that created layer and giving the error-000732. Ultimately I want to apply symbology from one layer to many layers generated from "SaveToLayerFile". Is there a work around it?

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = 0
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Documents/Data/ArcGIS_WorkFiles/Metric_1/Monitors_Joined_With_PM_2000Size_AllCounties"
PM_Shapefiles = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

in_symbology_layer = "C:/Documents/Data/ArcGIS_WorkFiles/Metric_1/Monitors_Joined_With_PM_2000Size_AllCounties/Source_Symbology_Layer/Size2000_MaxTotalPM25_Layer.lyrx"

for shp in PM_Shapefiles: 
    FIPS = shp.replace("PM25Monitors_JoinedInMAPPM_2000Size_", "")
    FIPS = FIPS.replace(".shp","")
    FIPS = int(FIPS)
    print ("FIPS=%s" %(FIPS))

    arcpy.Delete_management("Layer_%s" %(FIPS))
    where_clause = '"TotalPM25">0.0001'
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("C:/Users/mthind/Documents/EMRE_Project/Data/ArcGIS_WorkFiles/Metric_1/Monitors_Joined_With_PM_2000Size_AllCounties/%s" %(shp), "Layer_%s" %(FIPS), where_clause)
    arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management("Layer_%s" %(FIPS), "Layer_Files_2000Size/Symbology_%s.lyrx" %(FIPS))

    symbologyFields = [["VALUE_FIELD", "PM_MTInMAP", "PM_MTInMAP"], 
                   ["COLOR_EXPRESSION_FIELD", "TotalPM25", "TotalPM25"]]

    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management("Layer_Files_2000Size/Symbology_%s.lyrx" %(FIPS), in_symbology_layer, symbologyFields)
```

[image]

Edit code to response @ 8:31 ET

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = 0
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/mthind/Documents/EMRE_Project/Data/ArcGIS_WorkFiles/Metric_1/Monitors_Joined_With_PM_2000Size_AllCounties"
PM_Shapefiles = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

in_symbology_layer = "C:/Users/mthind/Documents/EMRE_Project/Data/ArcGIS_WorkFiles/Metric_1/Monitors_Joined_With_PM_2000Size_AllCounties/Source_Symbology_Layer/Size2000_MaxTotalPM25_Layer.lyrx"

#workspace = "C:/Users/mthind/Documents/EMRE Project/Data/ArcGIS_WorkFiles/Metric_1/Monitors_Joined_With_PM_2000Size_AllCounties/OK"

for shp in PM_Shapefiles: 
    FIPS = shp.replace("PM25Monitors_JoinedInMAPPM_2000Size_", "")
    FIPS = FIPS.replace(".shp","")
    FIPS = int(FIPS)
    print ("FIPS=%s" %(FIPS))

    arcpy.Delete_management("Layer_%s" %(FIPS))
    where_clause = '"TotalPM25">0.0001'
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("C:/Users/mthind/Documents/EMRE_Project/Data/ArcGIS_WorkFiles/Metric_1/Monitors_Joined_With_PM_2000Size_AllCounties/%s" %(shp), "Layer_%s" %(FIPS), where_clause)

    if arcpy.Exists("Layer_%s" %(FIPS)):
        print("layer exists")
    else:
        print("Does not exist")

    if os.path.exists("Layer_Files_2000Size/Symbology_%s.lyrx" %(FIPS)):
        arcpy.Delete_management("Layer_Files_2000Size/Symbology_%s.lyrx" %(FIPS))

    arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management("Layer_%s" %(FIPS), "Layer_Files_2000Size/Symbology_%s.lyrx" %(FIPS))

    symbologyFields = [["VALUE_FIELD", "PM_MTInMAP", "PM_MTInMAP"], 
                   ["COLOR_EXPRESSION_FIELD", "TotalPM25", "TotalPM25"]]

    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management("Layer_Files_2000Size/Symbology_%s.lyrx" %(FIPS), in_symbology_layer, symbologyFields)
```

[image]

Comment: Try `print("C:/Users/mthind/Documents/EMRE_Project/Data/ArcGIS_WorkFiles/Metric_1/Monitors_Joined_With_PM_2000Size_AllCounties/%s" %(shp))`, does it look like a valid path to the shapefile?

Comment: Yes, used the "print" command you suggested and it gives a valid path. But it gives same error as before.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is identified in the 1st parameter of SaveToLayerFile as ERROR 000732, meaning the input layer (Layer_17011) "does not exist or is not supported".

Not sure, but think the key is in that SaveToLayerFile expects a Layer data type - MakeFeatureLayer outputs a Feature Layer data type.  According to the documentation, you can use getOutput(0) to return the result object (or you may be able to simply use [0] as I've seen in practice).  See http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm, and under the method overview is this quote:

> If the output of the tool, such as MakeFeatureLayer is a layer,
>   getOutput will return a Layer object.

Provided your MakeFeatureLayer provides valid output, then you should be able to do something roughly like this:

```
layer_to_save = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(<my shapefile>,
      "Layer_%s" % (FIPS), where_clause).getOutput(0)

arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(layer_to_save, <my lyrx filename>)
```

Otherwise, advise you do as BERA says in his above comment and test your string paths to make sure they're valid.

EDIT (7:45 PM Eastern):

According to your code, this is the problem line, the one that throws the error:

arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management("Layer_%s" %(FIPS), "Layer_Files_2000Size/Symbology_%s.lyrx" %(FIPS))

There are 2 parameters you need to check - one is the input feature layer, "Layer_%s" % (FIPS), and the output layer file,"Layer_Files_2000Size/Symbology_%s.lyrx" %(FIPS).

I now suspect the problem could be your lyrx file - you could check if it exists, delete it if it does, then run the save to layer process, as so:

```
if os.path.exists("Layer_Files_2000Size/Symbology_%s.lyrx" %(FIPS)):
    arcpy.Delete_management("Layer_Files_2000Size/Symbology_%s.lyrx" %(FIPS))
# then you should be free to write the file (if not locked)
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management("Layer_%s" %(FIPS), "Layer_Files_2000Size/Symbology_%s.lyrx" %(FIPS))
```

...of course, if that does not work, by process of elimination you should check that your layer obj you're trying to write-to-file exists and is valid....you can use something like:

```
if arcpy.Exists("Layer_%s" %(FIPS)):
    print("layer exists")
    # carry on with processing...
```

Not to forget, you need to add an import for os at the beginning of your script...you can do that alongside your import arcpy statement:

```
import arcpy
import os
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it gives same error "ERROR 000732: Input Layer: Dataset Layer_17011 does not exist or is not supported". One thing I wanted to mention: The script ran successfully one time before (initially before I posted my question on StackExchange), but when I ran again, it never successfully ran. Is there something in the settings to change or any parameter in the environment to change? The generated layer from "MakeFeatureLayer_management" is stored in in-memory. Is it something to do with that?

Comment: Yes definitely may be key....in that case you should set the overwrite output env variable to true, else if you can also delete a feature layer before proceeding with an attempt to essentially replace it.  [arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True]

Comment: Yes, if you see my script above, I have already included that: arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True. Still there is same error.

Comment: Looks like you already have the overwrite setting turned on, so what you should try is an If statement to check for the lyrx file in the dir you’re writing to and explicitly delete the file before rewriting it.  The management toolbox has a Delete tool, otherwise you can delete files easily via strictly Python.  ...first put in a statement if arcpy.Exists(<your layer file>)...

Comment: Yup, I included that (delete any previous in memory file) in my original script as well: arcpy.Delete_management("Layer_%s" %(FIPS))

Comment: Sorry, I confused MakeFeatureLayer with saving to file - it is saving to file that is your problem, so you should be checking whether the file on disk exists and delete that before attempting to rewrite it.

Comment: Can you write the syntax that you are referring to? MFL stands for?

Comment: The issues is that "MakeFeatureLayer" does create the layer file. But "SaveToLayerFile" is not accepting that created layer file in previous step. The arcpy.Delete_management("Layer_%s" %(FIPS)) syntax is doing the job that you are mentioning, correct? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No.  I’m not at a terminal now to check, but that syntax would not delete a file on disk.  You need to make sure to include the file extension.

Comment: you mean this: arcpy.Delete_management("Layer_%s.lyrx" %(FIPS))?

Comment: No.  Standby, I am back at the terminal and will edit my answer above.

Comment: I followed your suggestions (updated). I added my updated code and result (image) in the main question above. Please check. When I ran if arcpy.Exists("Layer_%s" %(FIPS)): print("layer exists"); it results that the layer does not exist. I am confused why it does not exists since the syntax before (MakeFeatureLayer_management) creates it (runs tool successfully).

Comment: Good, you’ve successfully isolated your problem, now you have to figure out why your MFL process fails....for troubleshooting, I would just run up to the MFL process with the where_clause applied.  Set addOutputsToMap to True so the layer(s) can be added to the map for your further examination...could be your where_clause is faulty — that’s for you to figure out.  For ease of troubleshooting, make a pared down simplified copy of your code for testing purposes.  Later, when you’ve got a simple process running to completion that is repeatable, then add the looping, etc.

Comment: No field delimiters on FIPS - check that in your where_clause.

Comment: When I remove where_clause, it still gives same error. When I run the script only till "arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("C:/Users/mthind/Documents/EMRE_Project/Data/ArcGIS_WorkFiles/Metric_1/Monitors_Joined_With_PM_2000Size_AllCounties/%s" %(shp), "Layer_%s" %(FIPS))", it runs fine. But problem is that the generated layers are not displayed in TOC even when AddOutputsToMap is true.

Comment: Ok So it worked! When AddOutputsToMap is true, it worked. But I have new problem now: My saved symbology files are not showing any symbology from parent file.

Comment: Mark this question answered and open a new question concerning applying symbology...you need a fresh start, and you’ll likely get more responses too.